# Justifying casual claims in algebraic topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question, geometric-topology

Especially when you study algebraic topology, you'll encounter a lot of casually stated claims, involving homeomorphisms, quotient space constructions, or deformation retracts. One very famous example would be the identification of $S^n$ as the quotient of $D^n$ by its boundary $S^{n-1}$. Some people may well accept this fact simply by imagining the case $n=2$ where a disc 'wraps up' to become a sphere, and then by hand-waving. More cautious people might look for an explicit formula for a homeomorphism, which is not so difficult in this example.

However, as I am not even close to a genius topologist, I occasionally face topological claims which are neither easily visualized in mind (at a first glance) nor easily proved by a detailed formula. For instance, the following examples in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology do not resonate with my (inborn) intuition.

$\cdot~ \mathbb{R}^3 - S^1$ is homeomorphic to a $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $S^1 \vee S^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$\cdot~$ An orientable surface of genus $g$ is obtained by identifying pairs of edges from a polygon with $4g$ sides.

$\cdot~$ Given a 2-simplex $[v_0, v_1, v_2]$, identifying the edges $[v_0,v_1]\sim [v_1,v_2]$ produces a Mobius band.

Please note that I am not asking for visualization or formal proofs for these specific examples. To me they are somewhat justified but not perfectly. That is, I do have some ways to explain each of these to myself, but I do not consider them as satisfying as a well-written proof in analysis. However, I also don't want to spend much time finding a rigorous argument each time I come across something like these. Believing that I am not the only person in the world feeling this sort of awkward dissatisfaction, I would be very happy to learn his/her attitude or opinion on my worries from someone who had gone through a similar problem.

Edit2:
As Theoretical Economist provided a better paraphrase of the question, I would like to include it.
Would there be a strategy to justify non-intuitive topological claims in a mathematically satisfactory (or acceptable) way, but not writing down all the tedious details?
I think there should be some common way of reasoning, considering how many topological statements there are which everyone agrees with but no one actually writes the proof down.

Edit:
So my question is, to those who are experienced in topology:
Haven't you ever felt uncomfortable with some casual arguments because they weren't intuitively so clear to you? In cases when you felt so, did you always bother to 'rigorously' prove the argument?
I am asking this because I am not good at quickly understanding or coming up with intuitive topogical imagination, and also believe that it does not significantly hinder studying and understanding core ideas of AT, but it still disturbs me sometimes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: A topology student *is* required to have the ability to produce a rigorous argument for these kinds of constructions, and having that ability is a pre-requisite for Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology" book. If you have not developed that ability, I would look for a good topology textbook with lots of quotient constructions.

Comment: My experience is that once you write enough of them down, you develop an intuition and comfort with the hand waving. The actual formulas can be very messy, and in homotopy theory you aren't so picky about a model for a homotopy type anyway, you just use the most convenient one for the purpose at hand. Some of your examples are more from the Geometric Topology end, and in that case, comfort with such identifications is essential. I never was that good at it and that's why I did algebraic topology!

Comment: Sorry if the question was too vague. I think I wanted to ask people who are more experienced in topology than me how they overcome this sort of discomfort, if they ever had one. I will edit the question soon.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Necessity for feeling comfortable about all these miscellaneous (but not trivial) constructions is being an obstacle for me to engage deeper in topology, or specifically geometric topology as @Justin Young mentioned. I will admit that I haven't gone through an extensive training involving a bunch of topological constructions as Lee Mosher said, but I did not mean that I am unable to produce rigorous topological arguments. Just wondering if really everyone who is beginning to study AT should already be the master of topological intuition..

Comment: Your question as stated (even after the edit) still reads like something that would be primarily opinion-based. Perhaps it would be better if, instead, you asked for techniques/strategies for dealing with claims that are not intuitive for non-experts but are asserted without proof.

Comment: @Theoretical Economist Thanks for pointing out. That subjectivity was the reason why I hesitated a lot before posting this question, even if I was very eager to somehow bring up the discussion. I agree that your restatement is a better way to express the inquiry.